# How can I achieve different ordering of flex elements based on media screen?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement the display of div elements as in the image shown below, using the display: flex property. The left is how it should be displayed on mobile screens, and the right is how it should be displayed on big screens. I'm wondering if anyone can help me since I can't do it at all.

[image]

Comment: would be easier with a grid. What have you tried so far? Alternativly search for grid or masonry layout and show your attempt.

Comment: You can't do this with flex, as it only works in "2D". You can use Grid, which lets you organize elements horizontally and vertically simultaneously. Read https://moderncss.dev/3-css-grid-techniques-to-make-you-a-grid-convert/ as an intro to Grid.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `css grid` instead, it's much easier.

see the snippet:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "g1 g1 g1 g2" "g3 g3 g4 g2" ". . g4 .";
  gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr
}

.g1 {
  background: red;
  grid-area: g1;
  min-height: 60px;
}

.g2 {
  background: green;
  grid-area: g2;
  min-height: 60px;
}

.g3 {
  background: blue;
  grid-area: g3;
  min-height: 60px;
}

.g4 {
  background: yellow;
  grid-area: g4;
  min-height: 60px;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-areas: "g1" "g2" "g3" "g4";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <div class='g1'>1</div>
  <div class='g2'>2</div>
  <div class='g3'>3</div>
  <div class='g4'>4</div>
</div>
```